# Grouping nested repeater fields output using ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to output my nested ACF repeater fields such that the output is as follows:

**Group 1 Name**

Group 1 Array of values:

- Donor Name
- Company Name
- Photo URL

**Group 2 Name**

Group 2 Array of values:

- Donor Name
- Company Name
- Photo URL

I have the following code so far:

```
    $sponsor_group_names = array();
    $donor_names_list = array();
    $donor_company_names_list = array();
    $donor_photo_urls = array();

    $donors_group_list = array();
    if (have_rows('sponsor_group')):
        while ( have_rows('sponsor_group')) : the_row();
            $sponsor_group_name = get_sub_field('sponsorship_group_name');
            array_push($sponsor_group_names, $sponsor_group_name);
                if (have_rows('group_donors')):
                    while ( have_rows('group_donors')) : the_row();
                        $donors_group = get_field('group_donors');
                        array_push($donors_group_list, $donors_group);

                        $donor_name = get_sub_field('donor_name');
                        array_push($donor_names_list, $donor_name);
                        $donor_company_name = get_sub_field('donor_company_name');
                        array_push($donor_company_names_list, $donor_company_name);
                        $donor_photo = get_sub_field('donor_photo');
                        array_push($donor_photo_urls, $donor_photo);
                    endwhile;
                endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
```

And I am outputting this as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($sponsor_group_names as $group): ?>
<h2 class="text-primary mb-3">{{$group}}</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important">

    <?php
    $iterator = 0;
    foreach ($donor_names_list as $donor): ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 contact-card" style="min-width: 300px;">
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important">
                <div class="col-lg col-6"><img src="{{$donor_photo_urls[$iterator]}}" class="donor-photo"></div> <!--https://via.placeholder.com/100-->
                <div class="col-lg col-6 donor-info"> <p>{{$donor}} </p> <p> {{$donor_company_names_list[$iterator]}} </p></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php $iterator++;
endforeach; ?>

</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This output gives me different Group names for 1 and 2, but outputs the same info for company name, photo url, and donor name. I would ideally like to set up my code so that it uses a `key=>value` like `$donor_photo_urls['group 1']` but my previous attempts at mimicking what I saw on support forums for ACF have resulted in NULL output.

Ultimately I want to print unique arrays for each group name. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you post a screengrab (or JSON) of your repeater setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your repeater is set up having `group_donors` as a nested repeater within `sponsor_group` here. Using the `get_field()` function on a repeater will actually return an associative array with all sub fields and any repeaters within them. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

As such, you should be able to do something like the following to output all of your groups and their nested donors.

```
foreach (get_field('sponsor_group') as $sponsorGroup) : ?>
    <h2 class="text-primary mb-3"><?= $sponsorGroup['sponsorship_group_name'] ?></h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important">
        <?php foreach ($sponsorGroup['group_donors'] as $groupDonor) : ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 contact-card" style="min-width: 300px;">
                <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important">
                    <div class="col-lg col-6"><img src="<?= $groupDonor['donor_photo'] ?>" class="donor-photo"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg col-6 donor-info">
                        <p><?= $groupDonor['donor_name'] ?></p>
                        <p><?= $groupDonor['donor_company_name'] ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

<---Working---->

foreach (get_field('sponsor_group') as $sponsorGroup) : ?>





" class="donor-photo">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).